# asyncLocalStorage requires a global localStorage object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, server-rendering

I'm trying to persist data using `redux-persist`. Here is my code:

```
import { createStore as _createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createMiddleware from './middleware/clientMiddleware';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import {persistStore, autoRehydrate} from 'redux-persist';

export default function createStore(history, client, data) {
  // Sync dispatched route actions to the history
  const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);

  const middleware = [createMiddleware(client), reduxRouterMiddleware];

  let finalCreateStore;
  if (__DEVELOPMENT__ && __CLIENT__ && __DEVTOOLS__) {
    const { persistState } = require('redux-devtools');
    const DevTools = require('../containers/DevTools/DevTools');
    finalCreateStore = compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : DevTools.instrument(),
      persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
    )(_createStore);
  } else {
    finalCreateStore = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(_createStore);
  }

  const reducer = require('./modules/reducer');
  // const store = finalCreateStore(reducer, data);
  const store = finalCreateStore(reducer, data, autoRehydrate());
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') persistStore(store);

  if (__DEVELOPMENT__ && module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./modules/reducer', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(require('./modules/reducer'));
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

It works fine with a single flow. But if I refresh page on any page except homePage, everything disturbs on page. I got following warnings as well:

```
[1] redux-persist asyncLocalStorage requires a global localStorage object. Either use a different storage backend or if this is a universal redux application you probably should conditionally persist like so: https://gist.github.com/rt2zz/ac9eb396793f95ff3c3b
[1] Warning: React can't find the root component node for data-reactid value `.15mzo5h179c.3.0.0`. If you're seeing this message, it probably means that you've loaded two copies of React on the page. At this time, only a single copy of React can be loaded at a time.
```

P.s. I'm using [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) boilerplate

Comment: `localStorage` only lives on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You want to conditionally create your store using the localStorage store enhancer only when you're running on the client.

```
...
const reducer = require('./modules/reducer');
let store;

if (__CLIENT__) {
    store = finalCreateStore(reducer, data, autoRehydrate());
    persistStore(store);
} else {
    store = finalCreateStore(reducer, data);
}
...
```

Comment: Maybe try instead, "if (typeof window !== 'undefined') persistStore(store);"

Comment: still same issue? Should I share complete redux creation module?

Comment: Yes, post the code that composes the finalCreateStore function and how you create your store.

Comment: I just updated my question, please have a look there. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Well, it removed this warning : `redux-persist asyncLocalStorage requires a global localStorage object` but page is still disturbing. Static files are not being uploaded. I'm not confident but I think it may be server-rendering issue. Anyway, thanks for your time.